# Xcode 14 fails to locate project classes when accessing through interface builder

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, xcode14

[image: I showed with red arrow where the problem happened]

I want to open `WishListSupporterViewController` source code file by clicking the arrow in the **Class** field. However nothing happens when clicking this icon in Xcode 14. Is this feature broken or something is wrong with configuration of my project?

Comment: Xcode 12 also shows an I-beam cursor. Does WishListSupporterViewController.h exist? Or is it WishListSupporterViewController.swift and is the module missing?

Comment: Yes I have WishlistSupporterViewController.h. I think feature is broken. @Willeke

Comment: Xcode 14.1 is here, and it's still broken for me.

Comment: I send feedback to Apple. They didn't solve this problem. They didn't reach to me. I don't know the reason. I can share my feedback link. https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/11536127

Comment: This issue solved in Xcode 14.3 Beta version.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the feature is broken in the latest stable Xcode version (**14.0 (14A309)**).

The same works perfectly well with the same project in the previous version (**13.4.1 (13F100)**)

Don't forget to [submit an issue with Feedback assistant](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will report to Apple assistant. I want to be sure about this matter.